# Excel Formula to Calculate Percentage on Different Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to calculate the percentage of completed items from a a list.
Let's say:

```
    #of Visit    Place  Comment
    --------     -----   -----
    355          A      abc
    345          B      xyz
    322          C
    301          D
    288          E      pqr
    245          F
```

So, what I am trying to do is see how many of the rows have been completed (whose Comment cell is not blank).

To that I will add all of the visits whose comment filed is not blank, and divide it by total visit.

However, I am trying to achieve this in excel, preferably on a different sheet. So, data is on one sheet, and stats on the other.

I need assistance with the formula. Any help is appreciate.

**Updated:**

Great, this is very helpful. But, I still need to find out how to add up the values in A if B is filled. In other words, COUNTA(C2:C7) = 3, but what I am looking for is the sum of A corresponding to COUNTA(C2:C7). So, 355 + 345 + 288.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For summing, what you're looking for is `=SUMIF(Sheet1!C:C,"<>",Sheet1!A:A)`.

So, to get the percentage of visits that have comments, the final formula would look like this: `=SUMIF(Sheet1!C:C,"<>",Sheet1!A:A)/SUM(Sheet1!A:A)`

In terms of your example numbers, there are 988 visits with comments, divided by 1856 visits total, so 53%.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the range that could possibly contain comments is fixed (i.e. the formula doesn't have to figure out how many places there are) then the formula would be:

```
=COUNTA(rng)/ROWS(rng)
```

...where `rng` is the range we're looking at.

If the formula were on the same sheet, then `rng` would be in the format you're probably already familiar with, something like `C2:C7`

If the formula is to go on a different sheet, then the range simply needs to reference the sheet the data is on, so it becomes somethink like `Sheet1!C2:C7`

Full formula:

```
=COUNTA(Sheet1!C2:C7)/ROWS(Sheet1!C2:C7)
```

You'll need to format the cell containing the formula as a percentage to get it to display in a user-friendly way.

Comment: Great, this is very helpful. But, I still need to find out how to find add up the values in A if B is filled.

Answer (score 1):

I like Jason's answer.  If, however, you don't know how far down the range should be examined, you can use a column that **is** filled.  In Jason's case:

```
=COUNTA(Sheet1!C:C)/COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)
```

**EDIT#1:**

If there are *Headers* in the columns, then use:

```
=(COUNTA(Sheet1!C:C)-1)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1)
```

Comment: Column headers will make this formula inaccurate.

Comment: @Excellll  **OUCH!!**  you are correct!.............I will fix.

Comment: Great, this is very helpful. But, I still need to find out how to find add up the values in A if B is filled. In other words, COUNTA(C2:C7) = 3, but what I am looking for is the sum of A corresponding to COUNTA(C2:C7). Thank you.